# Removing parts of audio while leaving other parts intact

Tags: editing, audio

This is a bit of a niche question but, I recorded a video with a strange bird call that I was going to post somewhere for someone to ID it but there were people talking so you can’t hear the bird call that well. The human voices are at a lower pitch than the bird call. Is there any way in any software to cut out the lower pitch human voices but leave the higher pitch bird call so you can hear it better?

Thanks so much!

Tip11000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a go at doing this in Adobe Audition by switching the view from Waveform to Spectral Frequency Display. If the birds and the voices occupy totally different parts of the frequency spectrum, you may be in luck.  Use the Spot Healing Brush to erase the unwanted frequences in your audio file.

[More on adobe's blog page](https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2020/01/24/quickly-remove-unwanted-audio-content-with-the-spot-healing-brush-in-adobe-audition)